# JFileChooser causes log4cplus:ERROR No appenders could be found for logger (AdSyncNamespace)

Tags: jfilechooser, log4cplus

Searching for a solution to a problem I am having with JFileChooser. It is the exact same problem as the one found here: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2532293. If someone could give me a solution and explanation for the error that would be awesome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [log4cplus:ERROR in python when calling for tkinter file dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19576586/log4cpluserror-in-python-when-calling-for-tkinter-file-dialog)

Comment: it is so weird. but you should uninstall autodesk360!(not you of course. your problem is definitely solved by now)