# log4cplus:ERROR in python when calling for tkinter file dialog

Tags: python, tkinter, xlrd, log4cplus

I've written a little program in python that pulls data out of an .xls spreadsheet using xlrd with tkinter file dialogue boxes for opening/saving the files. Earlier today, the program was running fine, but I recently installed Autocad Electrical 2014 on my laptop for work, and now when I run the python script, I get the following errors when the script pulls up the dialogue boxes:

```
log4cplus:ERROR No appenders could be found for logger (AdSyncNamespace).
log4cplus:ERROR Please initialize the log4cplus system properly.
log4cplus:ERROR No appenders could be found for logger (AdSyncNamespace).
log4cplus:ERROR Please initialize the log4cplus system properly.
```

The only thing that has changed between the times this script worked and when I get the errors is the installation of AutoCAD.

What is going on here and how can this be avoided?

Comment: this has nothing to do with tkinter. Those are related to the log4cplus library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error has shown up a few times already. It appears that something called [Autodesk 360](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/Maya-General/log4cplus-ERROR/td-p/4290303) can be uninstalled, which fixes the issue.